# Entity Framework authentication and non-existent databases

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have some old code which worked a few years ago (according to my repository commits, all tests succeeded) that is no longer working. I suspect changing my Windows login to my email address associated with Microsoft Live may have introduced the problem, but I have no idea what to do to fix it. Incidentally I can use SQL Server Management Studio to use both connection strings to log in.

I'm using Entity Framework to create a context based upon a connection string in `app.config`. The "touch" command is supposed to create the database. However, this is throwing errors for both Windows and SQL Server authentication. This is the code for the Windows authentication:

```
var context = new CherrySqlDbContext("WindowsAuth");
var touch = context.Users.Count();
```

Connection string:

```
Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False
```

Stack trace:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException was unhandled by user code
>   HResult=-2146233087
>   Message=The underlying provider failed on Open.
>   Source=EntityFramework
>   StackTrace:
>
> at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection(Boolean shouldMonitorTransactions)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__5()
>   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1..GetEnumerator>b__0()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
>
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.b__3[TResult](IEnumerable`1 sequence)
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
>              at System.Linq.Queryable.Count[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
>              at cherry.Tests.Integration.TransactionTest.RollbackShouldSucceed() in D:\2015\cherry\cherry.Tests.Integration\TransactionTests.cs:line 74
>
> InnerException:
>   Class=11
>   ErrorCode=-2146232060
>   HResult=-2146232060
>   LineNumber=65536
>   Message=Cannot open database "TestDB" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'MicrosoftAccount\fubar@example.com'.
>   Number=4060
>   Procedure=""
>   Server=localhost
>   Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
>   State=1
>   StackTrace:
>
> at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>                   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>                   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>                   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>                   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>                   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
>                   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
>                   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
>                   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.b__36(DbConnection t, DbConnectionInterceptionContext c)
>                   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
>                   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
>                   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.b__2()
>                   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0()
>                   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
>                   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation)
>                   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
>              InnerException:

The code for testing SQL Server authentication

```
var context = new CherrySqlDbContext("UserAuth");
var touch = context.Users.Count();
```

Connection string:

```
Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Integrated Security=False;User ID=sa;Password=myPassword;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False
```

Stack trace:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException was unhandled by user code
>   HResult=-2146233087
>   Message=An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure. If you are connecting to a SQL Azure database consider using SqlAzureExecutionStrategy.
>   Source=EntityFramework.SqlServer
>   StackTrace:
>
> at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
>              at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
>              at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1..GetEnumerator>b__0()
>              at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
>              at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>              at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.b__3[TResult](IEnumerable`1 sequence)
>              at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot)
>              at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
>              at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
>              at System.Linq.Queryable.Count[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
>              at cherry.Tests.Integration.TransactionTest.RollbackShouldSucceed() in D:\2015\cherry\cherry.Tests.Integration\TransactionTests.cs:line 74
>
> InnerException:
>   HResult=-2146233087
>   Message=The underlying provider failed on Open.
>   Source=EntityFramework
>   StackTrace:
>
> at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection(Boolean shouldMonitorTransactions)
>                   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
>                   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__5()
>                   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
>              InnerException: 
>                   HResult=-2146233087
>                   Message=An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure. If you are connecting to a SQL Azure database consider using SqlAzureExecutionStrategy.
>                   Source=EntityFramework.SqlServer
>                   StackTrace:
>                        at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
>                        at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation)
>                        at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
>                   InnerException: 
>                        Class=20
>                        ErrorCode=-2146232060
>                        HResult=-2146232060
>                        LineNumber=0
>                        Message=A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)
>                        Number=233
>                        Server=localhost
>                        Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
>                        State=0
>                        StackTrace:
>                             at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>                             at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>                             at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>                             at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>                             at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>                             at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
>                             at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
>                             at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
>                             at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.b__36(DbConnection t, DbConnectionInterceptionContext c)
>                             at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
>                             at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
>                             at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.b__2()
>                             at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0()
>                             at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
>                        InnerException: 
>                             ErrorCode=-2147467259
>                             HResult=-2147467259
>                             Message=No process is on the other end of the pipe
>                             NativeErrorCode=233
>                             InnerException:

Comment: Your second connection string, did you accidentally paste the first connection string on the end?  "ConnectionString: Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Integrated Security=False;User ID=sa;Password=myPassword;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False **Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False**"

Comment: No, that was a typo in formatting my question. I fixed it